# how to access the RMS of a mobile phone?

Tags: java-me

I created a T9 application updater for mobile but I have not been able to get access to the mobile phone's RMS.so I can't update the phones's T9 RMS. Please how do I go about this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't access the T9 dictionary from standard JavaME.
T9 is handled by the system software. When you add TextFields in your MIDlet, it is the system software that calls T9 functionality. You have no control of it from within JavaME.

It would require a special API to be able to access/edit T9 dictionary, and I don't think such an API exists. (If it does, it would only exists on very few phones).